# Understanding SRAM chain sizing guide

Tags: chain, sram, 1x11

[image]I'm having trouble understanding the latest SRAM chain sizing guide.

I run a 1x11 on a full suspension bike (not eagle).

You can see in the image there two scenarios for chain overlap. They have the 1x11 listed on the top with the hardtail eagle. Does this mean always use +2 links overlap whether HT or FS 1x11?

Comment: It looks very much like you should use the 4-link overlap, not the two-link overlap.

Comment: You can also use the two-link overlap system when the rear suspension is fully compressed, i.e. all the air drained. Follow the technical manual (page 15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you've interpreted their insane hieroglyphics correctly. They're saying the top is for Eagle hardtails or all 1x11, 1x8, and 1x7. The lower is full squish Eagle only.

Comment: After installing the chain I can confirm this is correct.